# how to determine if this integral converge or not?

Tags: improper-integrals

I should determine whether this is a convergent or divergent integral. The problem is that I don't know how to start.
i need to use the comparison test but i don't know where to start.
$$
 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx
$$

Comment: Compare with ${1\over e}\int_0^1 {1\over x}dx$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Nice. Why don't you submit that as an answer...?

Comment: @DavidMitra  how can i continue from here? how to show that your example is not converge?

Comment: $\int_0^1 1/x\,dx=[ \ln x]_0^1=\ln 1 -\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\ln x=\cdots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e^{-x}$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ and positive there, for $0\le x\le1$ you have $e^{-x}/x\ge e^{-1}/x$. Consequently, you can compare with the integral $\int_0^1 {dx\over e\cdot x}$ to show your integral diverges.